# Tabulação via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, seletores

Possuo um campo com a classe "codigoBarra" onde será utilizado leitor de código de barras para preenche-lo, ao fim da leitura com o leitor ele gera uma \n, já consegui capturar isto e tratar, porém, quando isso acontecer, preciso que o focus passe para o próximo campo da tela que estiver habilitado.

[image: exemplo]

Na foto, ao terminar de digitar o SPI, que é o número que será lido pelo leitor, deverá passar para o CNPJ pois os campos de DATA e SITUAÇÃO estão desativados para a edição.

Comment: Como é a estrutura do HTML?

Comment: Como você verifica o `\n` no campo? Você pode usar essa mesma verificação e colocar o foco no campo que você deseja. `$("#campo").focus()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tentar selecionar o próximo campo e setar o foco.

Exemplo genérico:

```js
$(document).on('keyup', 'input[type=text]:enabled:not([readonly])', function(event){

    if ( this.value.length == $(this).attr('maxlength') ){
        // Seleciona todos os inputs que estão habilitados
        $els = $('input[type=text]:enabled:not([readonly])');
        console.log($els);
        $i   = $els.index(this);
        
        if ($els.length > ($i + 1)){
            $($els[$i+1]).focus();
        }
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" maxlength="11" /> <br />
<input type="text" maxlength="11" disabled /> <br />
<input type="text" disabled /> <br />
<input type="text" maxlength="11" /> <br />
    <input type="text" disabled /> <br />
<input type="text" maxlength="11" /> <br />
```

O exemplo acima é o mais genérico possível, devido nenhum código ter sido postado na pergunta.

Comment: o próximo input da tela é um botão... consegui da seguinte forma:
$("input[type=text]:enabled:not([readonly]):eq(" + ( parseInt( $(this).index("input[type=text]:enabled:not([readonly])")) + 1 )+ ")").focus();

Comment: Então @JonathanBarcela, como você não postou o código do seu form ficou difícil simular seu ambiente. Bom que conseguiu.

Comment: É que eu não posso publicar o código pois os direitos autorais pertencem a empresa, tentem me explicar o máximo possível na pergunta. Obrigado pela ajuda, @KaduAmaral.

Comment: Ah, tranquilo @JonathanBarcela, sei como é. Se minha resposta te ajudou a chegar nesse resultado marque-a como aceita. ;)